# Reading list from a file

Tags: list, file, prolog

I don't have much experience in Prolog.

```
add(first, second) :-
    see('telefon_375319.txt'),
    read(L),
    seen,
    M = [[first, second] | L],
    tell('telefon_375319.txt'),
    write(M),
    nl,
    told.
```

The purpose of the above code is to:

1. Read the list (which is a list of list) from a file (into L).
2. Add the list [first, second] at the beginning of the list (it might be at the end or even in the middle).
3. Save it to a file.

The result I get in the file is following:

`[[x, y], end_of_file].`

The result should be:

`[[x, y], and here should be the rest of the list].`

I don't know why ,but `Prolog` read a text `end_of_file` into L instead of the list which is stored in the file.

What's wrong?

Comment: You should show what the contents of your test file, `telefon_375319.txt` look like before you ran your test above.

Comment: So what happened with this? Any resolution?

Answer (score 0):

`end_of_file` is not text. It’s atom and it’s read when the file ends. But in my SWI Prolog I see that an empty line must me placed at the end of the file in order to read it correctly. Searching for relevant info on that.

Comment: Search not successful. When reading file `[hello].\n`, just `end_of_file` is read. When reading `[hello].\n\n`, `[hello]` is read (and `end_of_file` after that).

Answer (score 0):

I modified the original slightly to use variables, not atoms. I also added writing a period (`.`) after the list that's written since `read` expects to see it:

```
add(First, Second) :-
    see('telefon_375319.txt'),
    read(L),
    seen,
    M = [[First, Second] | L],
    tell('telefon_375319.txt'),
    write(M), write('.'),
    nl,
    told.
```

Contents of `telefon_375319.txt`:

```
[[a,b],[c,d]].
```

Then run:

```
| ?- add(x, y).

yes
```

New contents of `telefon_375319.txt`:

```
[[x,y],[a,b],[c,d]].
```

Run:

```
| ?- add(z, w).
```

New contents of `telefon_375319.txt`:

```
[[z,w],[x,y],[a,b],[c,d]].
```

Other than the two changes that I made which I mentioned above, I don't see anything wrong with the predicate based upon the described desired behavior. I ran this on GNU Prolog and SWI Prolog on Linux, and SWI Prolog on Windows 7 and it worked as expected in all cases. The text file ends in a single `\n` in the case of Linux, and `\r\n` in the case of Windows.